# The program does not give the desired output . Wrong implementation of FIFO ?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, data-structures, queue, fifo

This is a FIFO program using `linked list` . The program does not give the desired output but generates a long loop which stops after sometime and there is a message that the program has stopped working. What is the problem ?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct node {
      int data;
      struct node* previous; // This pointer keeps track of the address of the previous node
};

struct queue {
      node* first;
      node* last;
};

node* dataNode_P_A; 

bool loop = true;

struct node* enterData();
struct node* enter_N_Data();
void displayQueue();

int main() {
    struct node* dataNode= enterData();

    while( loop ) {
        cout << "Want to enqueue ? Press y/n : ";
        char ans;
        cin >> ans;
        if( ans == 'y' )  {
          struct node* dataNode_N = enter_N_Data();
        } else {
          break;
        }
    }

  displayQueue();
}

 struct node* enterData() {
    cout << "Enter the number : ";
    dataNode_P_A = new node;  // Now dataNode points to a chunk allocated to node
    cin >> dataNode_P_A->data;
    dataNode_P_A->previous = NULL; // this is set to NULL because no one follows till now   
    queue* q = new queue; 
    q->first = dataNode_P_A; // this pointer points to the first element
    return dataNode_P_A;
}

struct node* enter_N_Data() {
    cout << endl << "Enter the number : ";
    node* dataNode = new node;
    cin >> dataNode->data;
    dataNode->previous = dataNode_P_A; 
    queue* q = new queue;
    q->last = dataNode; // this pointer points to the last element
    return dataNode;
}

void displayQueue() {
    while( dataNode_P_A != NULL ) {
        cout << dataNode_P_A->data  << endl;
        dataNode_P_A++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Never seen a linked list with only a pointer to the previous node.  N

Comment: Hmmm, strange.  Normally you would track the next node in a singly-linked list, not the previous...

Comment: What is the desired output? What is the *actual* output? Where precisely does it stop working? Time to fire up your debugger.

Comment: @TonyTheTiger: It's a standard single linked list. Whether that's "next" or "previous" is arbitrary.

Comment: @Cat: just said I've never seen it done that way.

Comment: For the OP, start by stopping writing C.

Comment: @ razlebe It stops after showing a huge list of values !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are constructing `queue`s and then abandoning them.

You fail to update `dataNode_P_A`, so that you are not constructing a *list* so much as a *tassel*.

You invoke `dataNode_P_A++` when you clearly don't know what it means.

You have written a long, complicated piece of code without testing it along the way.

You should start over, and go step by step.

Comment: Oooh, good catch - I'd missed the fact that enterData and Enter_N_Data both don't update dataNode_P_A.

Answer (score 4):

Where to begin...  First off the queue data structure isn't particularly used for anything.  But that's not the root of your problem.  That lies here:

```
 void displayQueue() { 
   while( dataNode_P_A != NULL ) { 
       cout << dataNode_P_A->data  << endl; 
       dataNode_P_A++; 
   } 
}
```

When iterating through a linked list, you move to the next element by navigating to ->previous:

```
 void displayQueue() { 
   while( dataNode_P_A != NULL ) { 
       cout << dataNode_P_A->data  << endl; 
       dataNode_P_A = dataNode_P_A->previous; 
   } 
}
```

Having said that, you're doing some other things that are questionable - like modifying your global list (dataNode_P_A).  That's not a problem in your example, but it can be a problem if you ever want to do anything to the list other than display it.

Here's another version of displayQueue that doesn't have that problem:

```
 void displayQueue() { 
   node *entry = dataNode_P_A;
   while( entry != NULL ) { 
       cout << entry->data  << endl; 
       entry = entry->previous; 
   } 
}
```

Comment: "you move to the next element by navigating to ->previous"
Easy to remember, simple to use.

Comment: The `displayQueue` function will always display **only** the first number entered because `dataNode_P_A` never changes.How can i overcome this ?

Comment: I guess I'm a bit confused by the question - dataNode_P_A will never be null because enterData creates at a single dataNode_P_A element.

Comment: Also look at Beta's answer - he caught one other problem I missed - you don't update dataNode_P_A in enterData and Enter_N_Data, which means that the global list isn't updated.

Answer (score 0):

You should edit your **`enter_N_Data()`** function like:

```
node* temp; // global as others in your program

struct node* enter_N_Data() {
cout << endl << "Enter the number : ";
node* dataNode = new node;
cin >> dataNode->data;
temp = new node;
temp = dataNode_P_A;
dataNode_P_A = dataNode;   // update dataNode_P_A

dataNode->previous = temp; 

queue* q = new queue;
q->last = dataNode; // this pointer points to the last element
return dataNode;
}
```

and keep everything same while following the suggestions by @ Larry Osterman and @ Beta.